# subscription to Rx.Observable from string not working on value assignment

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This is a basic rxjs question that I could not find an answer to.  Say I make a string observable, and then after a certain amount of time I want to assign a new value to it.  The new value does not seemed to be observed because it does not get logged.  I know rx is working because the initial value is logged as a cascade of characters.  Can you please explain what I am doing wrong, and what I need to modify in order to be able to log this new value?  Here I'm using a setTimeout function to update the variable, but in reality it will be an ajax request that returns a JSON object that holds that value.

```
var observableId = "hwebd788ew98ew9";

var sourceAid = Rx.Observable.from(observableId);
var subscriptionAid = sourceAid.subscribe(

function (x) {
    console.log('changed!', x);
},
function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
},
function () {
    console.log('Completed');
});


setTimeout(function() {       
    observableId = "yrth5yu56uy56";
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pushing data to an array

```
var first = [];

var s1 = new Rx.Subject();

s1.subscribe(first.push.bind(first));

s1.onNext('I');
s1.onNext('am');

setTimeout(function() {       
    s1.onNext('late');
    console.log('late',first);
}, 2000);

console.log('first'first);
```

if you run this you will get

```
"first"
["I", "am"]
"late"
["I", "am", "late"]
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the reason why the "initial value is logged as a cascade of characters" is because `Observable.from` accepts an iterable as a parameter. Hence when you pass it a string: it is treated as an array, and each character  becomes an iteree the result of which is each character being logged at one at a time.

the easiest way to create an Observable that

1. Has an initial value.
2. Can have more values passed in over time

is to use a BehaviorSubject :

```js
var stream = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('test0');

stream.subscribe(hash => console.log(hash));
var testCount = 0;

setInterval(() => stream.next(`test${++testCount}`), 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.3/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

If you would like to pass this observable out to another class or function, and don't want them to be able to call `next` on your BehaviorSubject you can pass them an observable with the `asObservable` method:

```
return stream.asObservable();
```

Now you can keep updating your BehaviorSubject and the consumer will only be able to subscribe to events, but not create new ones.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do `Observable.next()` to push data to all subscribed methods.

Let me explain your problem

```
//this is a normal variable. updating anything will not effect observable
var observableId = "hwebd788ew98ew9";

//sourceAid will be an observable and the intitial value will be observableId
var sourceAid = Rx.Observable.from(observableId);

// you are subscribing the value which is good.
var subscriptionAid = sourceAid.subscribe(

function (x) {
    console.log('changed!', x);
},
function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
},
function () {
    console.log('Completed');
});

// here youa re changing observableId which is normal javascript veriable and it has nothing to do with observable
setTimeout(function() {       
    observableId = "yrth5yu56uy56";
}, 2000);

// you need to eimt/change/add value to 'sourceAid' as it is subscribed and responsible to notify all methods subscribing it for updates.

//this will update
sourceAid.next("yrth5yu56uy56")
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, (https://runkit.com/embed/2jmrvfbv9u27) ... because `Observable`s don't have a `.next` method. `Observer`s do have a `.next` method. Thats why you would use a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`   which are both an `Observer` and  an `Observable`.

Comment: the runit is not editable. As your sourceAid is subscribed, it need to be updated. not the observableId.

Comment: There's a "Clone and edit" button at the bottom of the page?